# Не работает ordering в ListView Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Почему может не работать ordering?

Вообще изначально сортировка у меня указана в модели. Она работает:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    #объявление полей
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('price', )
```

Я хочу изменить ее в ListView на сортировку по name:

```py
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    ordering = ('name', )
```

От этого вообще не происходит - нет ошибки, но нет и эффекта. Товары выводятся по-прежнему по цене. В выборке order_by я не использую. Только filter:

```py
 def get_queryset(self):
        current_category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'), is_active=True)
        qs = Product.objects.filter(categories=current_category, is_active=True)
```

Куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копать в сторону вызова метода базового класса и возврата значения

```
def get_queryset(self):
    current_category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'), is_active=True)
    return super().get_queryset().filter(categories=current_category, is_active=True)
```

Comment: Это сработало, но я ничего не понял. Вы не могли бы объяснить почему нужно вызывать get_queryset родительского класса?

Comment: Вы наследуете свои представления от обобщённых, в частности от `ListView`, для того, чтобы использовать код, написанный за вас разработчиками Django - все механизмы сортировки, пагинации, валидации и прочее. Но если вы переопределяете метод `get_queryset`, то фреймворк вызовет только ваш код, просто проигнорировав полсотни строк кода из базовых классов и миксинов. Это основы ООП.

Comment: Все, теперь я понял что случилось. Спасибо)